# Rails Generator vs Create Files by Hand

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have notice that there are many files created by generators (not only scaffold, but `rails generate` in general) that I don't use.

So I came up with the following questions (about best practices):

1. Do you use generators or it is preferable to create by hand only files you need?
2. If you use generators, do you keep all generated files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use generators specifically to help you build individual files. For instance, you could use

```
rails g model Video title:string link:string
```

to create a model file with those as attributes, but you don't need to use scaffolding to generate everything (if that's what you're referring to)

Personally I like to use a combination -- it really depends on the project. But I'd tell you not to have extra files that you aren't using, so definitely delete the ones you aren't using (or don't plan to use).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. However I was referring to rails generate model/controller/etc ...not only to scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

i do use the generators and just delete the files. It is probably because I am lazy but I find this easier.

Especially with models, because it includes the migration.

Honestly it all comes down to just preference. Just don't scaffold...